# Оператор delete: удаление массива

Tags: массивы, c++

Здравствуйте. :) 
Вот такой вопрос возник, почему вот этот после выполнения

```
int *x = new int[2];  delete x;
```

идентичен вот этому

```
int *x = new int[2];  delete []x;
```

Везде где читал, сказано что массив нужно удалять вторым способом.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Если вы выделяли память при помощи `new[]`, вы *обязаны* освободить её с помощью `delete[]`. Так гласит стандарт.

Освобождение такой памяти как-то по-другому (`delete` без `[]` или вообще `free`) является [Undefined Behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/276994). Если в программе есть Undefined Behaviour, она имеет право вести себя *как угодно*: может ничего плохого не делать, может вылететь в **любой** точке, отформатировать ваш винчестер или выбросить из окна вашего кота.

You have been warned.

Comment: я понимаю что это по стандарту, но вот смотрите, 
тут после выполнения первого варианта и после второго.
http://joxi.ru/uploads/prod/20130612/4a2/824/a9a319f964270bcb1a866d7349db79628f00438d.jpg?v=2.1.2

Comment: ну теперь понятнее, спасибо :)

Comment: Почитайте про undefined behaviour, забавная и опасная штука.

Comment: читаю, благодарю)

Comment: Вот вам немного литературы: [0](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213), [1](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html), [2](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html), [3](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_21.html).

Comment: Палец вверх за кота :)

Answer (score 3):

Если Вы выделили массив элементов, то этот массив и нужно удалить. New делает malloc на *sizeof(объект)* и вызывает конструктор объекта, new[] делает malloc на *sizeof(объект) * кол-во_объектов*, вызывает конструкторы для каждого будущего объекта **и записывает информацию о том, память для скольких объектов была выделена**. Куда и как эта информация записывается вопрос отдельный (плюс бывает ситуации когда это информация не нужна).

Вызывая `delete` Вы говорите компилятору "удали этот **один** элемент по такому-то адресу". Оператор delete[] же читает сколько объектов расположено в выделенной памяти (как мы помним, оператор new[] сохранил это число в процессе своей работы), вызывает для каждого их них деструктор, а после вызывает `free()`, "отдавая память назад ОС". Именно поэтому для памяти, выделенной через `new/new[]` нужно вызывать `delete/delete[]` соответственно. Контроль за тем, что для оператора выделения должен быть вызван соответствующий оператор освобождения лежит на программисте.

Comment: Оператор `new` вовсе не обязан по стандарту использовать `malloc` (он может, например, запросить прямо у системы без посредничества `malloc`).

Comment: hashcode превращается в Хабр

Answer (score -1):

x - указатель на первый елемент массива, поетому delete x; удаляет только первый елемент.

Comment: у меня после выполнения удалились оба элемента

Comment: @Artemiy_plus_plus, а как вы узнали сколько элементов удалилось?

Comment: @nullptr, неправда

Comment: я произвел вывод элементов

Comment: Artemiy_plus_plus: Оператор `delete` вовсе не обязан изменять значение удаляемых элементов. Наоборот, для оптимизации он обычно этого **не** делает. (Попробуйте откомпилировать программу в Release-режиме, в Debug-режиме оптимизации выключены для удобства отладки.)

Answer (score -7):

Оператор удаления массива называется `delete[]`, а не `delete []`.
В выражении `delete []x`, `[]x` - это что за операция? `[]x` - нет такой операции !

Comment: `delete` и квадратные скобки - это отдельные лексемы, поэтому совершенно неважно как их писать. Без разницы `delete[] x` или `delete []x` или `delete [ ] x`, пробельные символы игнорируются.

Comment: Я понимаю что компилятор понимает по-разному. Компилятор вообще квадратные скобки понимает в нескольких интерпретациях. Компилятор даже так понимает  "delete   [        ]x". Попробуйте, он понимает ! Но с точки зрения здравого смысла И на низком уровне перевода кода в команду удаления это так: "delete[] x" ЭКВИВАЛЕНТНО  _delete_memory_region(void* _address_begin_region);

Comment: И `delete[] x,` и `delete []x` для компилятора совершенно идентичны и представляют собой одну и ту же последовательность четырех лексем. Если пробел не там оскорбляет ваши эстетические чувства, то так и скажите, и не надо подводить под это какие-то фантастические теории. Кстати, если уж говорить про генерацию кода, то `delete` транслируется во `free`, а не в какую-то загадочную функцию `_delete_memory_region`.